# Type mismatch when passing an array

Tags: vba, excel

I keep on getting an error when I try and pass this value to an array, essentially I am working with exchange rates, I have the currency in the second dimension of the array **ary**() and I am looking to retrieve a data point in a table that is 2 cells away from the element stored in the array.

Now I believe the problem has something to do with the value being a number and the array being a variant, however I cannot solve the problem.

```
Option Explicit

Dim fxary(), y

ws.Select
Set Rng = Sheets("BEXR").Range("C2:C" & Sheets("BEXR").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)

For i = 1 To UBound(ary, 2)
    If ary(2, i) <> ary(2, UBound(ary, 2)) Then
        For Each y In Rng
            If Sheets("BEXR").Range(y.Address).Value = ary(2, UBound(ary, 2)) And Sheets("BEXR").Range(y.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value = ary(2, i) Then
                fxary() = Sheets("BEXR").Range(y.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value ' error occurring here
                fxary = ary(1, i)    
        End If
        Next y
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Can you please post a complete sub? (Omit the irrelevant parts but include the variable declarations)

Comment: I used just dim for y, and Dim fxary() As Variant for the array. The value going into the fxary would be a number. Sorry if this is of no help.

Comment: Your code won't compile. You have `Option Explicit` but then have all sorts of undeclared variables. Furthermore, you never say what you are trying to pass arrays *to*. You seem to mean reading the values of a range to a variant array, but you are using terminology which is typically used when invoking subs or functions.

Comment: Hi John, the code has 400 lines, I have omitted all the lines not related to this specific problem. All the other variables are declared. Yes I want to pass the value from the range to a variant array.

Comment: You can check this out for some guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You don't have to have a perfect mcve for every question but you should at least have code that would compile (e.g. the beginning and end of the sub and variable declarations) and should comment where you left out stuff. Anyway, try `Dim fxary As Variant` and `fxary = ...`.

Comment: Just declare `fxary` as variant, *not* `fxary()`. A variant variable by itself is quite able to hold the values in a range as an array. In other words -- you need a variant which holds an array, not an array of variants.

Comment: What is the error messgae and what line does it occur on? If we can't compile to simulate you need to provide more information. Where is ary defined?

Comment: Hi guys, although your suggestion worked, the reason I am passing the value in the range into an array is because there can possibly be more than 1 value, in fact ideally I would be passing the values into another 2 dimensional arrays, see the edited code. Passing to a variant seems to just override every time, rather than storing multiple elements.

Comment: You are saying `fxary() = Sheets("BEXR").Range(y.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value` (which is equivalent to saying `fxary() = y.Offset(0, 2).Value`) but, even if it didn't throw a type mismatch error, that will leave only the last value of y.Offset(0,2).Value in the variable.  I think you need to set some sort of counter and use that as an index of fxary.

Comment: @dbmitch sorry, well put, the error occurs here - fxary() = Sheets("BEXR").Range(y.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value

Comment: @YowE3K actually I only want one value from here, but this is a loop within multiple loops.

Comment: So you want the loops to only return one value (the last one)?  Why not just work backward and return the first one and then exit the loop - that would save a lot of time.

Comment: The line causing your error (`fxary() = Sheets("BEXR").Range(y.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value`) is redundant because your editted code shows that you are resetting `fxary` to `ary(1, i)` on the following line.  So just delete the line causing the error as it is not achieving anything.

Answer (score 1):

*Your comments say that `I have omitted all the lines not related to this specific problem`, therefore I will post an answer based on the assumption that all the lines that **are** related to the problem have been included in the code in the question.*

The following comments should be made about your code:

- You have used `Option Explicit` but nowhere do you declare the size or type of the variables `i` and `ary`.
- Nowhere do you specify values for the variable `ary`.
- Your line saying `fxary() = Sheets("BEXR").Range(y.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value` is trying to assign a scalar to a vector, and will generate a Type Mismatch error.
- Your line saying `fxary() = Sheets("BEXR").Range(y.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value` is immediately followed by a line (`fxary = ary(1, i)`) replacing the value of fxary with something else, so the first line is redundant.
- All your references to `Sheets("BEXR").Range(y.Address)` can be replaced with `y`.
- You are executing through two loops (from 1 to whatever the second dimension of the undefined variable `ary` is and, within that loop, through every cell in column C of your sheet), but you are effectively only setting `fxary` once, i.e. to the value in the undefined variable `ary` where the first dimension's value is 1 and the second dimension's value is `i`.  (But I haven't been able to wrap my mind around the code enough to be able to work out which value of `i` that will end up being - I **think** it's worked out by looking at each row of your sheet that has a different value in column C than in column D, and the value in column C is equal to `ary(2, highest value)`, and then determining the highest value of i such that `ary(2, i)` will equal the value in column D.)

---

I believe you need to look at each of the above items before your code will do anything meaningful, but to resolve the **specific** problem you say you are having:

1) Change your declaration of fxary to

```
Dim fxary, y
```

2) Simply remove the line saying

```
fxary() = Sheets("BEXR").Range(y.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value
```

as that line is redundant (as I said in one of my earlier points).